# Is there a way to refer a shape's position to the ruler?

Tags: vba, position, visio

I want to extract data from a Visio drawing.

Various drawings, over which I have no control, are built using a principle of a 'Heading' timeline defined by Boxes that represent a period of time (e.g. 12 boxes may represent a Year, or may represent 3 years - months or quarters).

Shapes underneath the boxes represent different activity with the duration defined by the length of the shape (using the 'Heading' timeline as the scale).

I need to pull put the text of the activities and ascribe a start and end date.

The only means I can find to locate the shapes is PinX/PinY. The trouble with PinX is that it represents the 'Centre of rotation' and this does not have to be within the shape. I find that with many Copy and Pastings of shapes on a drawing PinX has a habit of moving around.

The ideal solution would be to use the ruler as a reference.

Comment: It occurs to me that forcing the PinX properties to the Default; Centre-Centre and LocPinX to width*0.5 (for the shapes that matter) may solve the problem.  I'll try this and report back however, I would still like to know if it is possible to define a shapes 'X' position in relation to the ruler.

Comment: I am even more confused now.  For example I have 2 shapes (both on the same layer and in all cases Pin Pos is Centre-Centre, LocPinX is 0.5*width and XRulerOrigin = 13mm).  Both Shapes are rectangles, both shapes have their Left Hand side  at Ruler 0), therefore simple math says that in each case PinX - LocPinX should produce the same result.  It doesn't why???

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the ruler is what you want to use. The origin of the ruler can be moved to aid with drawing. I think what you want is the position of the visible geometry of the shape with respect to the page coordinate system. The [BoundingBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.boundingbox) method will give you the coordinates rectangle that tightly encloses a shape relative to the page.

Comment: Thanks HappyMoose - that looks like a good solution.  Although it turns out that PinX properties are independent of Ruler.

Comment: @Nigel are you referring to the horizontal and vertical rulers on the top and left of the drawing window or the little ruler which may appear above shapes when editing text?